# Graphical Glitch after recent system update (Ubuntu 22.04.2)

Tags: graphics

[This is the glitch. A green discoloration appears and disappears periodically, the pink line is always there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUa9x.jpg)

These are the updates that were installed before the glitch appeared, though I don't really know if they are what's causing it.

```
Start-Date: 2023-06-20  11:34:21
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.117'
Install: linux-image-5.19.0-45-generic:amd64 (5.19.0-45.46~22.04.1, automatic), linux-headers-5.19.0-45-generic:amd64 (5.19.0-45.46~22.04.1, automatic), linux-modules-5.19.0-45-generic:amd64 (5.19.0-45.46~22.04.1, automatic), linux-hwe-5.19-headers-5.19.0-45:amd64 (5.19.0-45.46~22.04.1, automatic), linux-modules-extra-5.19.0-45-generic:amd64 (5.19.0-45.46~22.04.1, automatic)
Upgrade: gjs:amd64 (1.72.2-0ubuntu1, 1.72.2-0ubuntu2), libglib2.0-bin:amd64 (2.72.4-0ubuntu2, 2.72.4-0ubuntu2.2), libgjs0g:amd64 (1.72.2-0ubuntu1, 1.72.2-0ubuntu2), libx11-xcb1:amd64 (2:1.7.5-1, 2:1.7.5-1ubuntu0.2), libcap2-bin:amd64 (1:2.44-1build3, 1:2.44-1ubuntu0.22.04.1), libgdm1:amd64 (42.0-1ubuntu7.22.04.2, 42.0-1ubuntu7.22.04.3), libfwupd2:amd64 (1.7.9-1~22.04.1, 1.7.9-1~22.04.3), ubuntu-drivers-common:amd64 (1:0.9.6.1, 1:0.9.6.2~0.22.04.3), linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 (5.19.0.43.44~22.04.17, 5.19.0.45.46~22.04.20), libglib2.0-data:amd64 (2.72.4-0ubuntu2, 2.72.4-0ubuntu2.2), libx11-data:amd64 (2:1.7.5-1, 2:1.7.5-1ubuntu0.2), gdm3:amd64 (42.0-1ubuntu7.22.04.2, 42.0-1ubuntu7.22.04.3), libcap2:amd64 (1:2.44-1build3, 1:2.44-1ubuntu0.22.04.1), fwupd-signed:amd64 (1.51~22.04.1+1.2-3ubuntu0.2, 1.51.1~22.04.1+1.4-0ubuntu0.1), linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 (5.19.0.43.44~22.04.17, 5.19.0.45.46~22.04.20), linux-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 (5.19.0.43.44~22.04.17, 5.19.0.45.46~22.04.20), gir1.2-gdm-1.0:amd64 (42.0-1ubuntu7.22.04.2, 42.0-1ubuntu7.22.04.3), libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.72.4-0ubuntu2, 2.72.4-0ubuntu2.2), gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock:amd64 (72~ubuntu5.22.04.1, 72~ubuntu5.22.04.2.1), libpam-cap:amd64 (1:2.44-1build3, 1:2.44-1ubuntu0.22.04.1), libfwupdplugin5:amd64 (1.7.9-1~22.04.1, 1.7.9-1~22.04.3), libx11-6:amd64 (2:1.7.5-1, 2:1.7.5-1ubuntu0.2), fwupd:amd64 (1.7.9-1~22.04.1, 1.7.9-1~22.04.3), linux-libc-dev:amd64 (5.15.0-73.80, 5.15.0-75.82)
End-Date: 2023-06-20  11:34:38

Start-Date: 2023-06-20  11:35:05
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.117'
Remove: linux-image-5.19.0-42-generic:amd64 (5.19.0-42.43~22.04.1), linux-headers-5.19.0-42-generic:amd64 (5.19.0-42.43~22.04.1), linux-modules-5.19.0-42-generic:amd64 (5.19.0-42.43~22.04.1), linux-hwe-5.19-headers-5.19.0-42:amd64 (5.19.0-42.43~22.04.1), linux-modules-extra-5.19.0-42-generic:amd64 (5.19.0-42.43~22.04.1)
End-Date: 2023-06-20  11:35:08
```

The issue does not appear on a second screen, I'm not sure if that means it's a hardware issue? I don't have a lot of experience with linux.